# Melt and Filter a Pandas dataframe at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge pandas dataframe, with millions of rows and thousands of columns. 
See below for a sample.

```
X   Y   col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4   col_5   col_6   col_7   col_8   col_9   col_10
0   A   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
1   B   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
2   C   2   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
3   A   3   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
```

I want to melt the dataframe using `pd.melt` on `X` and `Y` for columns `col_1` to `col_10`. I will have many more columns in my original dataframe.

I can do it like this,

```
pd.melt(s, ['X', 'Y'], [x for x in s.columns if x not in ['X', 'Y']])
```

After melting, I will have a dataframe like this,

```
    X   Y   variable    value
0   A   1   col_1   0
1   B   1   col_1   0
2   C   2   col_1   0
3   A   3   col_1   0
4   A   1   col_2   0
5   B   1   col_2   0
6   C   2   col_2   0
7   A   3   col_2   0
8   A   1   col_3   0
9   B   1   col_3   0
10  C   2   col_3   0
11  A   3   col_3   0
12  A   1   col_4   0
13  B   1   col_4   0
14  C   2   col_4   0
15  A   3   col_4   0
16  A   1   col_5   0
17  B   1   col_5   0
18  C   2   col_5   0
19  A   3   col_5   0
20  A   1   col_6   1
21  B   1   col_6   1
22  C   2   col_6   1
23  A   3   col_6   1
24  A   1   col_7   1
25  B   1   col_7   1
26  C   2   col_7   1
27  A   3   col_7   1
28  A   1   col_8   1
29  B   1   col_8   1
30  C   2   col_8   1
31  A   3   col_8   1
32  A   1   col_9   1
33  B   1   col_9   1
34  C   2   col_9   1
35  A   3   col_9   1
36  A   1   col_10  1
37  B   1   col_10  1
38  C   2   col_10  1
39  A   3   col_10  1
```

I am just interested in rows with value as `1` so I will do

`melted.loc[melted['value'] == 1]`

to get the needed rows only.

But when my data is so huge, I am getting out of memory error because the melted data fill up my RAM and chokes it. Which perfectly makes sense.

I wanted to filter based on the variable while melting itself. Something like `melt_filter` so that I won't run out of memory.

In the example I have shown above the columns `col_6` to `col_10` just have `1` then it can be filtered before hand and then melted. But this is not the actual case. I will have some rows that will have mix of `0` and `1`. Hence I can't filter before hand.

Is something like this possible.? If yes how to do it.?

EDIT : Many comments explains to filter the data by some means and melt the data. I can't do that because in actual data no columns will be completely 0 and no column will be completely 1. It will be a mix of 0 and 1.

Comment: `df.melt(id_vars=['X', 'Y']).query('value == 1')` ?

Comment: @ChrisA he says he *can't* melt his data when it is that big because of an out of memory error.  He knows how to filter his data.

Comment: @user3483203 yes, I can't hold the melted data in memory. I am sure that after filtering it will fit perfectly.

Comment: Filter before maybe...? `df[df.filter(like='col_').eq(1).any(1)].melt(id_vars=['X', 'Y'])`

Comment: @ChrisA I may have columns with mixed values. ie some columns may have `0` and `1`.

Comment: @SreeramTP It's hard for me to test this right now, but here's a suggestion. Use `df.to_hdf` using `format=table` to store your `df` in-disk. Then, just `del df`. That'll clear tons of space in your memory. Now, with the list of columns you previously have stored in a list, just `read_hdf` in a loop specifying `columns=columns[beg:end]` as argument, where `beg` and `end` state how many columns you want to read. Just use your current code to `melt` it, then `filter` it to delete non-1 values, and again save to disk (as pkl or h5).

Comment: At the end, you'll have many small `pkl` files, just read them and merge in memory!

Comment: Not sure if it is an interesting solution for you, but with a loop for it may be one way: `x_y = df[['X','Y']]; 
pd.concat([x_y[df[col].eq(1)].assign(variable=col) for col in df.columns if col not in ['X','Y']], ignore_index=True, axis=0)` like this the rows with 1 are filtered before.

Comment: @Ben.T what if some columns have mix of 1 and 0 s.?

Comment: @SreeramTP doing `df[col].eq(1)` would select only rows with 1, so if the columns have two 1s and the rest is 0s, then `x_y[df[col].eq(1)]` will be only 2 rows.

Comment: @rafaelc I am doing something similar you mentioned right now. Making chunks and then melting followed by filtering. But I am looking for something without splitting the dataframe.

Comment: @Ben.T in my original data ie data before merging, I will have 0 and 1 one in every row. That is no row will be full 0 or full 1 but a mix of both. So selecting by some means will give same dataframe.

Comment: @SreeramTP because it is a loop over each column, I meant `df[col].eq(1)` will select the rows with 1 in one column only at each time. so it is not selecting means, but works on each column at a time

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
Thanks @rafaelc for the comment. I believe this solution using `np.nonzero` is much more memory efficient:

```
cols = df.columns[2:]
nonzeros = np.nonzero(df[cols].values)

# nonzeros consist of two arrays
# nonzeros[0] is the row coordinates of nonzero values
# nonzeros[1] is the col coordinates of nonzero values

# all we need is to extract rows at ['X','Y'] 
# and corresponding columns
# for each nonzero value:
pd.concat((df.loc[nonzeros[0], df.columns[:2]].reset_index(drop=True),
           df.columns[nonzeros[1]].to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
          ),
          axis=1
         )
```

Output (the value part is not important as it is 1 anyway):

```
    X   Y   0
0   A   1   col_4
1   A   1   col_5
2   A   1   col_6
3   A   1   col_7
4   A   1   col_8
5   B   1   col_4
6   B   1   col_5
7   B   1   col_6
8   B   1   col_7
9   B   1   col_8
10  C   2   col_4
11  C   2   col_5
12  C   2   col_6
13  C   2   col_7
14  C   2   col_8
15  A   3   col_4
16  A   3   col_5
17  A   3   col_6
18  A   3   col_7
19  A   3   col_8
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but OP has a very specific constraint that the solution should be memory efficient. Likely `stack` will not solve the issue ! :)

Comment: @rafaelc thanks for the comment. How about this solution?

Comment: I will try out the answer and let you know how it went